# Fortran and C IDE

Tags: software-recommendation, programming, ide

I am currently working on a Fortran 77 program which includes several C routines, and using the KDevelop 3.5.3 (Using KDE 3.5.11) IDE for that matter. I had to stick to KDevelop 3.5.3 since the newer versions of KDevelop do not handle (or not easily: several attempts without success) that kind of multi-language application.

I am looking for a maintained IDE under ubuntu which would match these needs, since I am not sure using the old KDevelop version (3.5.3) is perennial, could anyone give me some advice?
Thank you in advance,       Manuel

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may take jEdit with addons that turn it into IDE.